# How can I optimize this SQL code further to run faster

Tags: sql, sql-optimization

```
UPDATE N SET [actType] = 'X'
FROM tableA N
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                  FROM tableA O 
                  WHERE O.clientCode = N.clientCode AND 
                        O.[userName] = N.[userName] AND 
                        O.[profile] = N.[profile] AND 
                        O.[rankID] = N.[rankID] - 1 
                 ) AND 
      N.[rankID] NOT IN (SELECT MIN(T.[rankID]) 
                         FROM tableA T 
                         WHERE T.[userName] = N.[userName]
                        )
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: It's going to depend on the data and the indexes you have

Comment: Hi @Sai Kiran, I'd recommend using CodeReview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions about optimization for working code. StackOverflow is predominantly used for non-working code. Hopefully this can be of help.

Comment: @Prebsus Possibly, but not in its current form. Lack of description, stripped of context and no accompanying `EXPLAIN`, we can't review this as-is.

Comment: @Mast, fair enough - I should've added that the posted needed to be edited before submitting to CodeReview. I suppose my comment was more of a principle matter (code problems = SO, code optimization = CR). But I'll keep your comment in mind for later

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with updatable *cte* :

```
with cte as (
     select N.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [userName] ORDER BY rankID) AS Seq
     from tableA N
)
update c
     set c.[actType] = 'X'
from cte c
where seq > 1 and
      not exists (SELECT 1  
                  FROM tableA O 
                  WHERE O.clientCode = c.clientCode AND 
                        O.[userName] = c.[userName] AND 
                        O.[profile] = c.[profile] AND 
                        O.[rankID] = c.[rankID] - 1 
                );
```

Your syntax suggests `SQL Server`. So, you can use.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try this :-)